# Java stream: map object data members to int list

Tags: java, java-stream

I need put the `A.a` and `A.b` to a `int` list in sequence:

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;
}

A a = new A();
a.a = 1;
a.b = 2;

List<A> list = Arrays.asList(a);
List<Integer> intList = list.stream().map(?).collect(Collectors.toList());
assert intList.equals(Arrays.asList(1,2));
```

How to do this using a Java stream?
And how to do this in reverse?

#### NOTE

By "*in reverse*" I mean to create a `List<A>` according to `List<Integer>`, because the example code is create `List<Integer>` according to `List<A>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `Stream` of the integers of `A` and `flatMap` this `Stream` so the integers of `A anA` become part of the outer `Stream`.

```
  List<Integer> intList = list.stream()
    .flatMap(anA -> Stream.of(anA.a, anA.b))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT
You [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550889/java-stream-map-object-data-member-to-int-list/52550958#comment92040820_52550958) also for the other way round:

```
  IntStream.range(0, intList.size() / 2)
   .mapToObj(i -> new A(intList.get(2*i), intList.get(2*i+1)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This implies a constructor in class `A`:

```
A(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

A quick test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new A(1, 2), new A(3, 4), new A(11, 22));
    List<Integer> intList = list.stream().flatMap(anA -> Stream.of(anA.a, anA.b)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(intList);
    List<A> aList = IntStream.range(0, intList.size() / 2).mapToObj(i -> new A(intList.get(2 * i), intList.get(2 * i + 1))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(aList);
}
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22]
[[1|2], [3|4], [11|22]]
```

Comment: in reverse is possible? get A object list according to int list

Comment: I mean this: List<A> alist = intlist.stream().map(?).collect(...). How?

Comment: converting `List<Integer>` to `List<A>`, where A has 2 Integer properties, is not possible unless you specify any functional condition.

Comment: So you have a `List<Integer> intlist` and want to get a `List<A> alist` of it?

Comment: This sould do it: `IntStream.range(0, intList.size() / 2).mapToObj(i-> new A(intList.get(i), intList.get(i+1))).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Strange, It looks pretty well solution.

Comment: Maybe because I have not made clear that the reverse way needs a corresponding constructor to be defiend. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: @NisargPatil What a functional condition you mean? In case you were missing a corresponding constructor in class `A` I added it to my answer.

Comment: @LuCio After I carefully read your code which do "in reverse", I found it is incorrect which handling index "i". It seems java stream only capable to handle elements one by one, so do this by stream seems no benefit. A simple for loop is better

Comment: @jean My bad. I missed `2*i` in the reverse way. Should have write and run in my IDE instead to copy it from the comment to the answer. Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(A).stream()
                              .flatMap(A -> Stream.of(A.a, A.b))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> reverseIntList = Arrays.asList(A).stream()
                                     .flatMap(A -> Stream.of(A.a, A.b))
                                     .collect(LinkedList::new, LinkedList::addFirst, (res, tmp) -> tmp.forEach(res::addFirst));
```